# Food sanitation

Tags: food-safety, sanitation

After getting ill due to bad sanitation of ingredients I decided to know a little better of the process of food hygienization.

It first occurred to me that a good first step would be to use lots of strong antibacterial products. Later on after reading I realised that most elements 'that-are-not-the-food-itself' (dirt & etc) are either water soluble or fat soluble, that means if you apply water combined with soap most of the stuff will go away (suppose you had sugar coating the food and olive oil, they would be rinsed).

If you went one step further and used an antibacterial product chances are you would probably get rid of anything that could do harm to your health.

My question is

a) are there any other big group of components that aren't neither water nor fat soluble and could be hazardous?

b) talking about general food sanitation which is usually more effective?

- the chemical act of removing through soap and water
- killing bacteria and other harmful organisms using antibacterial products

Any other general thoughts about sanitation is appreciated since this is a very important question of notorious public concern and I couldn't find expert opinions on the subject

Comment: There are many antibacterial substances that aren't chloride-based. Did you really mean to limit the choices to chloride products?

Comment: Sorry my ignorance but I didn't know that carey, I didnt mean only chloride based

Comment: OK, I fixed it for you. In the future, you can make changes to your questions by clicking the 'edit' link at the bottom left of your question.